# Scala: call a function to check if value exists, if not, create and add to list once

Tags: scala, for-loop, break, for-comprehension

Suppose I have these classes: `Foo(id: String)` and `Bar(fooId: String)`

I have a list of `Foo` objects, I want to create a list of `Bar` objects according to the id in the `Foo` objects. If a bar exists in the list I don't want to be created again and added to the list. I can use Set to solve this problem but I don't like it that way. It is just not right.

```
def createBars() = {
  var barList = List[Bar]()
  for {
    f ← fooList
    bar = findOrCreateBar(f, barList)
    barList = barList:+bar  //error

  } yield bar
}

def findOrCreateBar(f: Foo, barList: List[Bar]): Bar = {
  barList match {
    case Nil ⇒
      Bar(f.id)
    case _ ⇒
      val bars = for {
        bar ← barList
        if f.id == bar.id
      } yield bar

      if (bars.isEmpty) {
        Bar(f.id)
      } else {
        bars.head
      }
  }
}
```

I have a few issues:

***first*** the code above does not work because I get compile error in `barList:+bar` in `createBars`. The `:+` cannot be resolved! Also the compiler says that the `var` for declaring the `barList` could be val! So it seems that the compiler does not see the barList in the `barList = barList:+bar` as a list!

***second*** If I replace the var of barList to val I can't reassign the changed list to barList

***third*** I am using for comprehension in the `createBars` because I thought I have no other choice to return the barList. Using annotations and such just for a break in a regular foor-loop is not a nice idea, imho!

Please help!

Comment: What's your objection to using a Set?

Comment: @dhg basically, I think using Set in this situation would be good for managing the symptom but not to solve the problem at hand, namely avoid creating and adding the same object repeatedly. And I really want to make the code I have written work using list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
fooList.distinct.map(foo=>Bar(foo.id))
```

It is simple, efficient and keep the original list order.

Comment: The question was about reusing the elements with same id.

Comment: @Aivean - The question is pretty simple: "check if value exists, if not, create and add to list **once**". @mnish specifically noted that he does not want to use set (as others suggest) since this will create the (Bar) object multiple times. Note that `findOrCreateBar` function try to do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Really, it is waaaaay better to use a Set.  It's going to be much faster and much clearer.

```
fooList.map(foo => new Bar(foo.id)).toSet
```

But, anyway, here's a much cleaner version of what you're trying to do (ie, still uses a loop and `List` and `var` etc.):

```
def createBars2(fooList: List[Foo]) = {
  var barList = Vector[Bar]()
  for (foo <- fooList if !barList.exists(_.fooId == foo.id)) {
    barList :+= Bar(foo.id)
  }
  barList.toList
}

val fooList = List(Foo("a"), Foo("b"), Foo("c"), Foo("b"))
println(createBars2(fooList))
```

Answer (score 0):

You code has several flaws.

First of all, try to avoid mutable variables where possible.

Then, it's not efficient to search existent elements in `List`, as that requires O(n) time for single search and makes your algorithm run in quadric time.

And, at last, adding element at the end of `List` requires O(n) time too. If you can't avoid iteratively building of the list, use something mutable, like `List.newBuilder`.

Back to your problem, I'll solve it using recursive function, that takes and returns immutable values. (Don't look at ugly hack at the beginning, it's for demonstration purposes only).

```
var globalBarCount = 0

case class Foo(id: String)
case class Bar(fooId: String) {
  // this is hack to track Bar instances
  // never do this in real code
  val barId = { globalBarCount += 1; globalBarCount }
  override def toString: String = s"Bar#$barId($fooId)"
}

def createBars(foos:List[Foo]) = {
  def createBars0(fooToProcess: List[Foo], existentBarsIndex: Map[String, Bar],
                  reversedResultAccum: List[Bar]): List[Bar] =
    fooToProcess match {
      case Nil => reversedResultAccum.reverse
      case headFoo :: tail =>
        val newBar = existentBarsIndex.getOrElse(headFoo.id, Bar(headFoo.id))
        createBars0(tail, existentBarsIndex + (headFoo.id -> newBar), newBar :: reversedResultAccum)
    }

  createBars0(foos, Map.empty, Nil)
}

val fooList = List(Foo("foo1"), Foo("foo2"), Foo("foo3"), Foo("foo1"))
val barList = createBars(fooList)
println(barList)
```

Result is:

```
 List(Bar#1(foo1), Bar#2(foo2), Bar#3(foo3), Bar#1(foo1))
```

**UPD**  As I promised, adding new approaches.

You can use `foldLeft`, this approach basically does the same as above, but is shorter and thus preferred.

```
  val barList2 = fooList.foldLeft((List.empty[Bar], Map.empty[String, Bar])) {
    (accum, foo) =>
      val (resultListReversed, alreadyCreatedBars) = accum
      val newBar = alreadyCreatedBars.getOrElse(foo.id, new Bar(foo.id))
      (newBar :: resultListReversed, alreadyCreatedBars + (foo.id -> newBar))
  }._1.reverse
```

And the final approach. This one is really short, but you'd rather avoid using it, as it is not recommended to use mutable variables inside `map`.

```
  import scala.collection.mutable

  val barList3 = {
    val createdBars = mutable.HashMap[String, Bar]()
    fooList.map(foo => createdBars.getOrElseUpdate(foo.id, new Bar(foo.id)))
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I get this error:
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.hd$1()Ljava/lang/Object

Comment: @mnish That's strange. Check that you have all necessary imports. I'll update my answer adding couple of other shorter methods to do your task when I get home (in few hours).

Comment: @mnish added two new approaches, as promised. Check them.